# Yii2 virtual attribute naming - very strange uppercase/lowercase problem?

Tags: yii2, attributes, yii2-model

I am using Yii2 and I have the virtual attribute `notes2` (that is used by the GUI functions instead of database attribute notes):

```
class Order extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{    
    public function getnotes2() {
        return iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $this->notes);
    }

    public function setnotes2($value) {
        $this->notes = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $value);
    }
}
```

In this case both the following codes `$order->notes2` and `$order->Notes2` calls the setter and returns the right value.

But I have to use `$order->getAttributes()` function and default implementation of it does not include the virtual attributes. So I tried to override this function with:

```
public function attributes() {
    $attributes = parent::attributes();
    $attributes['notes2'] = 'notes2';
    return $attributes;
}
```

And now `json_encode($order->getAttributes())` includes empty `notes2` field, but `$order->notes2` (obviously - this causes the `notes2` field to become empty) has no value, but `$order->Notes2` has value!

Why such flip-flop of the register of the first character happens? How to declare correctly the virtual field that is available in `getAttributes()` as well?

But the following code (instead of override of `attributes()`)

```
public function getAttributes($names = null, $except = []) {
    return array_merge(['notes2'], parent::getAttributes($names, $except));
}
```

behaves as nothing has been overrides - both `$order->notes2` and `$order->Notes2` are calculated and there is no `notes2` (or `Notes2`) inside the `json_encode($order->getAttributes())`

Comment: OK, it seems to me that I expect too much from Yii2. I.e. if I declare notes2 as attribute then my getters/setters stop working and Yii2 considers this field as coming from database, i.e. virtual attributes https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-getset-methods can not be included in getAttributes, encode_json and similar methods.

Comment: Did you include that attribute as `safe` attribute in validation, or some other type. If not then there is your problem.

Comment: Of course, I also tried to include notes2 as safe attribute in validation rules, but this improved nothing.

Comment: Now I am staring to think that I should override beforeSave and afterFind methods and do notes conversion in both directions there and I should avoid notes2 completely. But there is no documentation about those events. Still searching...

Answer (score 1):

This case sensitivity problem is related to PHP limitation/feature - method names are case insensitive so virtual attributes provided by methods are also case insensitive - there is not difference if you define/call it as `getnotes2()` or `getNotes2()`, so there is no way to distinguish between `$order->notes2` and `$order->Notes2`.

This works differently for regular attributes (and properties) which does not use methods and they're not affected this case-insensitivity limitation. You didn't explain what you want to achieve, but regular attributes (defined by `attributes()`) and virtual attributes (provided by getters and setters) are two separate things and you can't mix them up - if you define attribute in `attributes()` it will be stored in internal array and getter/setter will be ignored (since regular attributes has precedence over virtual attributes).

In your case you defined the same attribute twice: once as regular attribute (in `attributes()`) and second as virtual attribute (with getter and setter). If you use this attribute with correct case (`$order->notes2`), regular attribute will be used. If case is incorrect (`$order->Notes2`) regular attribute will not be used (since it is case sensitive and there is no `Notes2` attribute) and virtual attribute will be used (since it will ignore case) as a fallback.

---

If the only thing you want to do is include `notes2` in `getAttributes()` try to override `getAttributes()` in this way and do not touch `attributes()` at all:

```
public function getAttributes($names = null, $except = []) {
    return array_merge(
        ['notes2' => $this->getNotes2()], 
        parent::getAttributes($names, $except)
    );
}
```

Not that this will ignore `$names` and `$except` arguments and always return `notes2` attribute.